# Mapping Functions In a Class C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, member, pointer-to-member

Ok so I am trying to map some of my member functions in the .h file this is to be able to use the map when I implement the code. However, after hours I have gotten nowhere so I would like suggestions or if anyone knows how to implement this. For reference these are the errors.

```
./Assembler.h:51:2: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    functions["load"] = load;
    ^~~~~~~~~
./Assembler.h:51:12: error: size of array has non-integer type 'const char [5]'
    functions["load"] = load;
              ^~~~~~
./Assembler.h:51:2: error: duplicate member 'functions'
    functions["load"] = load;
    ^
```

As for my header file it with the problem coming from the map:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Assembler {
public:

Assembler(string filename);//Argument will be passed from the os.cpp file
void parse();// Will go through the a file to output the .o file
void load();
void loadi();
void store();
void add();
void addi();
void addc();
void addci();
void sub();
void subi();
void subc();
void subci();
void ander();
void andi();
void xorer();
void xori();
void negate();
void shl();
void shla();
void shr();
void shra();
void compr();
void compri();
void getstat();
void putstat();
void jump();
void jumpl();
void jumpe();
void jumpg();
void call();
void ret();
void read();
void write();
void halt(); 
void noop();

private:
typedef void (*function)();
map<string, function> functions;
functions["load"] = load;
fstream in, out; //One will be the .s file while the other will be the .o file 
string opcode;
int rd, rs, constant, addr, machcode; //Different parts of the instruction
};
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class. You probably need to move `functions["load"] = load;` to a function's definition.

And also, you need to change them to:

```
typedef void (Assembler::*function)();
...
functions["load"] = &Assembler::load;
```

Comment: You can also initialize non-static data members. But you can't have statements, such as calling their members.

Comment: So what your saying is that the header a constructor is needed before I can actually map my functions.

Comment: @user2881196 Yes, otherwise compiler cannot find `functions`.

Answer (score 1):

Within C++ class declaration, you cannot have member initialiser or executable statement, Have this one

```
functions["load"] = load;
```

within constructor

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your class declaration: everything's compiling fine except

```
functions["load"] = load;
```

This is an assignment and initializes the functions map with something. That is **not** allowed in the declaration which is a "contract" (in the case of an interface) or "explanation" of how your class is composed and what methods/members has.

The right spot to put such an initialization is in your constructor's **definition** (i.e. in the part of the code that actually contains the code of your methods, specifically when the object gets created if you intend to initialize stuff.. i.e. the constructor).